# Using SdmxSource jar files in the Nexus Repository through maven (m2eclipse)

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, nexus

The error `Missing artifact org.sdmxsource:SdmxApi:jar:1.2.7` appears when defining dependencies in the m2eclipss.
I used this definition:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.sdmxsource</groupId>
<artifactId>SdmxApi</artifactId>
<version>1.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

What may cause such a problem? Is there another way to import packages from nexus repository(eclipse IDE)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried manually downloading the dependencies? See the sdmxsource help page: http://www.sdmxsource.org/sdmxsource-java/.

You could also use the parent tag in pom file:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>SdmxSourceBase</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.sdmxsource</groupId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</parent>
```

And the following repository in the maven settings.xml file:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sdmxsource</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>MTRepo</id>
                <url>http://sdmxsource.metadatatechnology.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>sdmxsource</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```